# Parity Config File

Tags: parity, light-clients

I'm looking for the best config file so that I can keep the smallest possible chain data on my machine, without running light mode.

I saw this config file posted somewhere, but my chain data is up to about 40GB after about 3 days:

```
[parity]
light = false

[network]
warp = true

[footprint]
tracing = "off"
fat_db = "off"
pruning = "fast"
pruning_history = 8
pruning_memory = 32
db_compaction = "hdd"

[snapshots]
disable_periodic = true
```

I think I read that this config should keep my chain data close to 10GB, but clearly that isn't the case for me.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using hdd, so please make sure that you are using parity 1.8.6. Earlier versions of parity are unable to sync on hdd. Regarding your question, please take a look at this awesome post by afri - [The Ethereum-blockchain size will not exceed 1TB anytime soon.](https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a)

Comment: I'm running 1.8.6, yes. Awesome article, thanks for the link.

Comment: If I change the mode I'm running in.. say I choose the --no-ancient-blocks option. Do I need to delete my existing DB and let it rebuild? Or will it take my DB that's currently 40GB and chop it down to 5GB?

Comment: There are two options. You can either export blocks, delete database and import them again or you can remove database and sync from scratch. Unfortunately, parity will not chop down the database automatically.